# Sharepoint sp start kit webparts question.Is there a script/content editor webpart?

Tags: web-part, spfx-webparts

I have provisioned the starter kiton my tenant and its really impressing with some additional webparts included. see below

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-starter-kit

But can we still get the script editor or the content editor webpart equivalent that use to be in the classic team sites?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The script editor is available out of the box in the classic experience. Maybe you are on SharePoint online and the scripting is disabled for the tenant then you will not see those web parts available.

If you are using modern experience that is not available out of the box but there are few open source web part you could use to substitute. 
Have a look at:

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor

https://medium.com/niftit-sharepoint-blog/add-the-script-editor-webpart-back-to-sharepoint-modern-experience-688a7b7208e4

Comment: Marek i'm referring to Modern UI though..Is this the case?

Comment: The script is enabled but no script editor in Modern UI sites

Comment: I am sorry @naijacoder I misunderstood your question I thought you were refering to classic experience. I have updated my answer.